# Lambda expression understandment

Tags: java, lambda, output

Could anyone explain me how what the output of this code would be and why?

I really don't understand how the lambdas exactly work.

```
interface IntProcessor {
    int process(int i1, int i2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntProcessor ip1 = (x,y) -> x*2 + y;
    IntProcessor ip2 = (a,b) -> a + b*2;
    int x = 3;
    int y = 7;
    x = ip1.process(x,y);
    y = ip2.process(y,x);
    System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: All relevant code should be posted here as text. Also, what specifically about them are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are a way of providing an implementation of an interface that has only a single abstract method (known as a `functional interface`).

Given the following interface declaration

```
interface IntProcessor {
    int process(int input1, int input2);
}
```

There were two ways to use it prior to Java 8.

One was to define a class and implement it.

```
    class MyIntProcessor implements IntProcessor {
        public int process(int a, int b) {
            return  a*a + b*b;
        }
    }
```

You could then do this.

```
        IntProcessor ip1 = new MyIntProcessor();
        int n = ip1.process(4,5);
        System.out.println(n); // prints 41
```

The other way was to create an anonymous class

```
        IntProcessor ip2 = new IntProcessor() {
            public int process(int a, int b) {
               return a*a + b*b;
            }
        };
```

And again.

```
        n = ip2.process(4,5);
        System.out.println(n); // prints 41
```

With lambdas, you can do the following:

```
        IntProcessor ip3 = (a,b)-> a*a + b*b;
        n = ip3.process(4,5);
        System.out.println(n); // prints 41
```

1. `(a,b)` are the arguments and they can be any values.
2. The `->` operator indicates a Lambda and the right side will 
   use the argument variables and do something with them.

The return type from the Lambda expression must match the return type of the `Functional Interface`.

The compiler will take care of finding the appropriate interface and ensuring the arguments match up with their types or report an error if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

IntProcessor is an interface, to instanciate it you need to define the functions, in this case `process`.

What you are doing as a lambda when creating ip1 and ip2 is defining a implementation of the interface on the fligth, I.e. defining the function while creating the object. In ip2 `(x,y)` represents the input of the function implementation, this is only a way of declaring what variables names you will use in the body, and to the rigth of `->` you are defining the body of the function.

When calling ip1.process(x,y), it will return `x*2+y`
When calling ip2.process(x,y), it will return `a+b*2` where `a` is the value of `x` passed to the function and `b` is the value of `y` passed to the function

Answer (score 0):

Your interface `IntProcessor` is a *functional interface*, as it has a *Single Abstract Method*. So, its implementations (your `ip1` and `ip2`) may be treated as lambda expressions.

You are making implementations on the fly. For example, your `ip1` can be viewed as

```
@Override
int process (int input1, int input2) {
    return x*2 + y;
}
```

So I think the actual output of your code would be `13, 13` (x=3*2+7, y=7+2*3).

Comment: `y = 7 + 2*3`? or better `y = 7 + 2*13`!

Comment: Ah yes of course; I forgot the `x` was changed by the line above.